# How to check type of reverse_lazy() object in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to do following:

```
u=reverse_lazy('xyz')
isinstance(u,str) # this is false since u is an object.

type(u) # <class 'django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__'>

isinstance(u,<class 'django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__'>) # doesnt work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `u.__dict__` you will get the following dict:

```py
{'_proxy____args': ('xyz',), '_proxy____kw': {}}
```

With that, you can get the initial args and then get the types of them.

```py
u=reverse_lazy('xyz')

initial_arg = u._proxy____args[0]

print(initial_arg)
# 'xyz'

print(type(initial_arg))
# <class 'str'>
```